# Maximum length of string

Tags: algorithm

We are given four strings s1, s2, s3 and s4 of the same length n. We need to find out the maximum possible length m of any string s so that:

For 1 <= i <= m,
there exist integers a(i), b(i), c(i) and d(i) belonging to [1, n] such that:

```
s[i] = s1[a(i)] where a(1) < a(2) < a(3) ... < a(m)

s[i] = s2[b(i)] where b(1) < b(2) < b(3) ... < b(m)

s[i] = s3[c(i)] where c(1) < c(2) < c(3) ... < c(m)

s[i] = s4[d(i)] where d(1) < d(2) < d(3) ... < d(m)
```

**Example** : Let n=10 and 4 strings are :

```
abcdefghij
abcdefijgh
ababckjdge    
cdeabcjdeg
```

Here answer is 5 as abcde or abcdg can be the required string s here. So maximum length is 5

How to find this length ?

Comment: The length of the longest common subsequence?

Comment: Looks like homework. What did you try ?

Comment: @aioobe LCS of 4 strings ?

Comment: Right. Is that what you're after?

Comment: I believe this is actually the longest increasing subsequence problem. There are multiple ways to solve this problem. An algorithm running in $O(n^2)$ can be achieved using dynamic programming [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-3-longest-increasing-subsequence/). However a more efficient algorithm running in $O(n log n)$ can be achieved [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-monotonically-increasing-subsequence-size-n-log-n/)